# Retrieving value from previous row in calculated column based on condition

Tags: date, row, spotfire

I am working on data in Spotfire. The table has 4 columns:

```
RowID
StudID
IMT
Date
```

I am trying to insert a calculated column in Spotfire to get the date from the previous row for a specific `StudID`. The date should not be filled for first entry for a specific `StudID` since it does not have a previous row.
Please refer to the image for details:

[image: Details in image]

Answer (score 0):

This will be a calculated column using the [OVER function](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_over_functions.htm), along with Intersect, Previous and the First aggregation.

```
First([Date]) OVER Intersect(Previous([Date]), [StudID])
```

It reads: over the intersection between (group of) the previous (to the current row) dates (which are the same) and the Student ID's (the same as the current row), give me the first row of that group. In your example, it will only ever return one date for that group, but the formula needs to be able to handle what happens if there are multiple rows. You may also need to think about whether this will happen in your data and what you're going to do about it. I.e.

```
StudID    Date
124-639   6/12/2018 
124-639   6/12/2018
124-639   6/14/2018
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for answering that, however the solution you provided only returns a date in the last row of every group and I want a previous date for each row except for the first row for of each group, which will be blank.

Comment: I don't understand. This replicates the calculated column in your example. [link](https://imgur.com/yZ9Lwi1)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of JasonJ's answer, it looks like his solution ran into issues when the dates of different StudIDs overlapped with one another.

So I was seeing something along the lines of this:

```
StudID, Date, Result
A, 10/1/2014, 
A, 10/10/2014, 10/1/2014
A, 10/17/2014, 10/10/2014
B, 10/20/2014, 
A, 10/21/2014,
B, 10/22/2014,
B, 10/24/2014, 10/22/2014
```

I created a weird workaround by adding another Calculated Column.
I doubt this is the IDEAL way to do this (I'd bet there's a better OVER function, but I couldn't identify it right off), but it looks like it's working.

First Calculated Column (Named **[CalcRank]**):

```
Rank(Concatenate([StudID],Year([Date]),If(DayOfYear([Date])<10,"0",""),If(DayOfYear([Date])<100,"0",""),DayOfYear([Date])))
```

Second Calculated Column:

Max([Date]) OVER (Intersect(Previous([CalcRank]),[StudID]))

Please note, you may have to pad your StudID with 0s to make sure it orders properly, like I did with the Date column.